# check for file existence in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know how I could check to see if a file exist based on user input and if it does not, then i would like to create one.

so I would have something like:

```
file_name = input('what is the file name? ')
```

then I would like to check to see if file name exist.

If file name does exist, open file to  write or read, if file name does not exist, create the file based on user input.

I know the very basic about files but not how to use user input to check or create a file.

Comment: What do you mean by "open it to write or read" - do you mean you want to do both, i.e. `r+` mode?

Comment: I just meant that i needed to do it in a way that will allow me to do either.

Comment: Well, you can always open a file for writing - if it exists, it will be cleared, if it doesn't exist, it will be created.

Answer (score 52):

if the file is not a file :(return False)

```
import os.path
if not os.path.isFile(file_name):
      print("The File s% it's not created "%file_name)
      os.touch(file_name)
      print("The file s% has been Created ..."%file_name)
```

**And you can write a simple code based on  (try,Except):**

```
try:
    my_file = open(file_name)
except IOError:
    os.touch(file_name)
```

Comment: What is os.touch? I can't find it at https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html or https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html .

Also "s%" should be "%s".

Comment: isFile() -> isfile()

Answer (score 5):

To do exactly what you asked:

You're going to want to look at the [`os.path.isfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) function, and then the `open()` function (passing your variable as the argument).

---

However, as noted by @LukasGraf, this is generally considered less than ideal because it introduces a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) if something else were you create the file in the time between when you check to see if it exists and when you go to open it.

Instead, the usual preferred method is to just try and open it, and catch the exception that's generated if you can't:

```
try:
    my_file = open(file_name)
except IOError:
    # file couldn't be opened, perhaps you need to create it
```

Comment: Hmm, what if the user enters the name of a directory? Wouldn't `.exists()` return `True`, but opening would then fail?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Good call; updated to `isfile()`.

Comment: That's exactly what you should **not** do, because that introduces a [race condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574518/how-does-using-the-try-statement-avoid-a-race-condition).

Comment: @LukasGraf *sigh* we're going down this again. Fine, I'll write up an entire explanation of exceptions as well for a user that is still figuring out how to use user input. Stand by...

Comment: @Amber no, just mark it as a duplicate, since this has been answered over and over again.