# How do I create directories in Python given a list of files with paths that may or may not exist?

Tags: python, file-io, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

How do I create directories in Python given a list of files with paths that may or may not exist?

I am downloading some files from s3 that may or may not exist in a certain directory. Based upon these keys that represent a potentially deeply nested directory that may or may not exist.

So based upon the key /a/number/of/nested/dirs/file.txt how can I created /a/number/of/nested/dirs/ if they do not exist and do it in a way that doesn't take forever to check for each file in the list.

I am doing this because if the local parent directories do not already exist `get_contents_to_filename` breaks.

**My Final Solution Using Answer:**

```
for file_with_path in files_with_paths:
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(file_with_path):
            os.makedirs(file_with_path)
        site_object.get_contents_to_filename(file_with_path)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: @AdamSmith I was about to say that may do it for me, but os.makedirs gets me even further.

Comment: I'm dumb. I read "How do I create DICTIONARIES" not "how do I create directories."

Comment: possible duplicate of [mkdir -p functionality in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600268/mkdir-p-functionality-in-python)

Comment: @LukasGraf Probably, thanks for pointing that out, although I feel like mine was a better question.

Comment: About: `if os.path.exists(file_with_path) is False`. 'is' tests if two variables point to the same object (reference equality). Although it will technically work, using `if not os.path.exists(file_with_path)` is arguably cleaner style-wise.

Comment: @ChristopheD ...but shouldn't be used anyway because it introduces a [race condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574518/how-does-using-the-try-statement-avoid-a-race-condition).

Comment: @Lukas Graf. I agree. Just catching the exception would be more pythonic too (in the 'easier to ask forgiveness then permission' sense).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use [os.makedirs()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs). This will create all intermediate directories if needed.

> Recursive directory creation function. Like mkdir(), but makes all
>   intermediate-level directories needed to contain the leaf directory.
>   Raises an error exception if the leaf directory already exists or
>   cannot be created. The default mode is 0777 (octal). On some systems,
>   mode is ignored. Where it is used, the current umask value is first
>   masked out.

Comment: @dkroy Almost. You also need to do some exception handling to get the [functionality of `mkdir -p`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600268/mkdir-p-functionality-in-python).