# How do I figure out the exception I need to catch?

Tags: python, exception, pyserial

This is a follow up question to [Pyserial: How to know if a serial port is free before open it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493379/pyserial-how-to-know-if-a-serial-port-is-free-before-open-it)
.

The post correctly says that:

```
try:
    ser = serial.Serial(port=portName)
except SerialException:
    print 'port already open'
```

will catch an exception generated when a script attempts to open a COM port that is open in another application (ie PuTTY).

My question is how, given the output, should I know that I need to use SerialException.  I initially was trying `except PermissionError` and that did not catch the exception. What makes it obvious that I needed to catch `SerialException` instead of `PermissionError`?

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 62, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM6': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)
```

Comment: The relevant documentation?

Comment: The [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial) -- "SerialException – In case the device can not be found or can not be configured."

Comment: Why dont you just catch common exception and then check it in finally block or in catch block only?

Comment: I understand that SerialException is covered in the documentation.  This is more of a general question about interpreting output. I saw PermissionError in the output and found that it was a built-in exception type and so tried to catch that.  My question should have been "Should I have been able to tell from the output that I needed to catch SerialException instead of PermissionError.  Or, should I have gone straight to the documentation?